# Implementing math recursion formula

Tags: c, recursion

I have such a formula:

[image]

I'm tryging to learn how to implement recursion in C, and wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    if(n%2 == 0)
        return a(2*(n-1)) + a(2*(n-2));
    if(n%2 != 0)
        return a(2*n) - a(2*(n-1));
}

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("%d\n", a(n));

    return 0;
}
```

However, my code gives me segmentation fault, what's the problem?

Comment: Put `printf("n = %d\n", n);` at the beginning of the `a` function. Then run your program again and you will find out what happens.

Comment: I see the problem, but first a question:  For the odd case, the image shows that the previous values are subtracted, not added.  Your code (both versions), on the other hand, adds for both the even and the odd case.  Which is correct?  Do you want to subtract for the odd cases?  This won't fix your segmentation fault, but the answer is needed to correct your code.

Comment: @TomKarzes: It's my mistake. I would like to implement the formula. I will edit the code.

Comment: The segfault is actually a stack overflow.

Comment: @Michael correct, the recursion isn't correct and it never terminates.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use recursion? Is the program too fast or consuming too little memory?

Comment: Ok, I posted a solution for you, along with an explanation.  I also sped it up a little by not taking the remainder twice, since if it's not even, then it must be odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
int a(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    if(n%2 == 0)
        return a(n-1) + a(n-2);
    else
        return a(n-1) - a(n-2);
}
```

What you have there is (mathematically) called a sequence.
Please take a look at the indices in your sequence then it probably makes more sense. You cannot just substitute 2n-1 there and FOR SURE not 2*(n-1) which is just wrong.

Furthermore:
The recursion is not the best way to implement that if you want to expand your sequence into a series. Then you better should start with 0, 1 and do that stuff iteratively.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is correct.  It's not as efficient as my version, but it works.

Comment: Your right. You should replace the != 1 case with an else like Tom Karzes did. I'll edit for future readers.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. But for an optimizing compiler replacing the last condition with `else` will likely not make a difference.

Comment: Wont trust in that. If you can take some optimizing stuff off the compilers shoulder like that, you probably should think of it beforehand. I never "trust" in compilers optimizing everything.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int a(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    if(n%2 == 0)
        return a(n-1) + a(n-2);
    else
        return a(n-1) - a(n-2);
}
```

The problem is that the `n` in your function is not the same as the `n` in your image, which is why it's creating confusion.  The thing to realize is that in the even case, you sum the previous two values, and in the odd case you subtract them, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from indexes:

```
int a(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    if(n == 1)
        return 1;
    if(n%2 == 0)
        return a(n-1) + a(n-2);
    if(n%2 != 0)
        return a(n-1) - a(n-2);
}
```